# What is equivalent to Datatables iSortCol_0 in Datatables 1.10.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I tried to update my datatable to the newest datatable version but I dont find an answer what the old variables called `iSortCol_0` and `sSortDir_0` are called in the `Datatables 1.10.2`. Does someone know that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean `javascript` instead of `java` ?

Comment: Nope its a java backend :) @mmcrae

Comment: They should be the same, aren't they?

Comment: @TheOddCoder you're not referring to the jQuery plugin called DataTables ? https://datatables.net/ that's what your `datatables` tag refers to, which is a thing in `javascript`

Comment: Yeah I just saw it sorry @mmcrae

Comment: The thing is it worked before I updated it and now it is always null @Andremoniy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the answer myself. The `iSortCol_0`is called `order[0][column]` in the new version and the `sSortDir_0` is called `order[0][dir]`. I realized that the documentation of the datatable tools ist not fully completed yet so be carefull if you use it in the future.